Estimating Parameters of a Censored Normal Distribution
I was recently presented with a statistics interview question phrased as follows:

You have a random variable $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, where both $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are unknown. Instead of directly observing $X$, we observe another random variable $Y$ with the following properties:

If $X \leq 10$ with 10 being the censoring threshold, we observe $Y = X$.
If $X > 10$, $Y$ takes on a different value that is independent of $X$.

How would you estimate $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ for $X$?

I am unsure how to approach this problem and believe this is due to gaps in my knowledge and understanding, struggling to think of any relevant theorem, corollary, or tools that could help solve this.
Potential Approaches:
Could anyone suggest some relevant concepts or estimation techniques that might be applicable here? For example, would mle or theorems from truncated/censored distributions be appropriate for handling the fact that $X$ is only observable under certain conditions by proxy of Y?
Any guidance on how to start or relevant resources would be greatly appreciated.

Do we know the distribution of $Y$ when $X>10$?

If you know the distribution of $Y$ or $Y|X$ when $X>10$ you could perform maximum likelihood estimation/Bayesian inference numerically without too much trouble

Thanks for these insights! Do you happen to have any references or resources on this approach in more detailed coverage?
I'd love to explore it further. I should have asked the interviewer about this, but I’d really appreciate any reading material you might suggest, assuming we know the distribution of Y or Y | X and what options that opens up. Thanks.

I think it's possible to use MLE, it's a mechanism of right truncation. For observations with X ≤ 10, the probability density function of these observations can be directly used. where data with X>10 has not been fully observed.For the case of X>10, since it only knows X>10, a survival function or truncation probability may be required.
Then calculate according to the steps of MLE normally, but numerical optimization methods may need to be used when solving the estimated values. Alternatively, the EM algorithm may also be a method, but it could be more complex.

Thanks for the recommendation, that really helps clarify the approach! Do you happen to have any references or theoretical texts in mind on using parametric survival functions in cases like this? I’d love to dive deeper into the theory to better understand it. Thanks
